How to Call _applyFilter Method from PlutoGrid When Clearing a CustomTextField in Flutter?
I'm working on a Flutter application using PlutoGrid, and I need to apply a filter to my grid when the text field is cleared. I have a method _applyFilter in my PlutoGrid dependency that applies a filter based on some criteria.
When the text in the CustomTextField is cleared, I need to call the _applyFilter method from the PlutoGrid dependency to reapply the filter based on the old filter picked.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
